# How to add a property in JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have a **JavaScript** object:

```
var credentials = 
{ 
    uid: response.authResponse.userID, 
    accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken 
};
```

How can I add in this object `name: response.something`?

Comment: What about `credentials.name = response.something` ?

Comment: why have i reveced down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript objects are dynamic.  That means that you can add any property to an object at any time simply by doing this:

```
credentials.name = response.something;
```

or equivalently:

```
credentials['name'] = response.something;
```

#### ECMAScript 5 only:

```
Object.defineProperty( credentials, "name", {
    value: response.something,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for your explanation. Ill mark this as soon as i can.